# IntelliJ shows splash screen and then quits

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio, jetbrains-ide

IntelliJ shortly shows a splash screen and then disappears. I also had downloaded Android Studio after which also does the same. I'm not sure how to run IntelliJ from command, since I didn't find idea.exe in my bin folder, not sure where else it could be located. I'm running a Windows 7 OS. Help is greatly Appreciated.

Comment: have you already tried to ask in their forum: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com

Comment: Actually I resolved it. I just uninstalled the program. Deleted the IntelliJ settings program in MyDocuments. Deleted the IntelliJ folder in my Program Files. Reinstalled IntelliJ. Worked like magic :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstalling the program, deleting the IntelliJ settings folder in "MyDocuments", deleting the IntelliJ folder in "Program Files" and Reinstalling a fresh new IntelliJ from the site resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue by:

1. Running Task Manager.
2. Find Idea process.
3. Right click
4. Click on Analyse Wait Chain
5. Select the service that is waiting
6. End the service
7. Restart Idea